# __init__() of derived class not being called?

Tags: python-3.x

I am very confused. I do not understand why the **init**() of class b is not called:

```py
from array import array

class b(array):
    def __init__(self, val: list[int]):
        super().__init__('h', val)

b([1,2,3,4])
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not list
```

The b.**init**() is not even being called. I confirmed that by replacing the `super().__init__('h', val)` call with a `raise ValueError`. Would appreciate any pointers on how to understand this. Thanks.
Python 3.11.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b.__init__` isn't being called, because the error is being raised by `array.__new__`.

```
from array import array

class b(array):
    def __new__(cls, val: list[int]):
        return super().__new__(cls, 'h', val)

b([1,2,3,4])
```

(Note that this kind of specialization violates the Liskov Substitution Principle; you cannot use an instant of `b` where an arbitrary instance of `array` might be expected.)